# How "realistic" is the way of holding star trek phasers?

Tags: star-trek, weapon

I've never fired a weapon but the design of Star Trek Phasers looks a little bit strange and uncomfortable to me (not the rifles though).

If we account for the no recoil effect of particle weapons and looking at the designs for Phasers for different eras of Star Trek, how easy would it be to hold and fire those phasers as compared with real fire arms of today? Does it resembles some kind of realistic approach or they are just made that way to look fancy?

Comment: Probably more realistic than the way they hold flashlights.

Comment: I remember somewhere that I read the cast complained that they don't know how they are supposed to aim the phaser props in a way that the post production people can insert a plausible beam. That's why the later developed phaser rifle props got proper sights. Unfortunately I don't remember the source.

Comment: @PeteBecker [No, not really](http://www.lachschon.de/item/120397-Teschenlampe/)

Comment: I've seen quite a few different phaser designs in the star trek universe. Can you attach a picture of the ones you're talking about?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Having been paid to shoot and teach shooting for several years...

As Tritium21 points out, *very much* about the way we handle projectile weapons is based on two things:

1. The stability and *intuitive position* required to aim the weapon
2. The stability required to recover from firing (whether that means maneuver to acquire a second, cover oneself from harm after loosing a shot, or recovering from recoil to line up a second shot)

This is true in one way or another all the way from darts to throwing knives to javelins to atlatls to slings to bows to firearms to actual energy weapons in use today.

**But a pure energy weapon has no recoil**

The recovery time is whatever the recharge would entail. No idea what this winds up being in the Star Trek world, but we'll just assume its close to zero and they can shoot as much as they want... because, um... science. (That said, after personal experience with capacitor-driven microwave weapons, this could be significantly annoying.)

So that leaves us with #1, and that is mostly about lining up the shot and *maintaining stability during the pull*. In this case the "pull" will be a button press instead of a draw, swing or trigger-pull, but the weapons themselves appear to be *incredibly lightweight* -- which means either the triggers are really, really lightweight themselves (sort of scary, considering what the business end can do) or are incredibly well aligned with the natural motions of the fingers and the lines of tension exerted from whatever is defined as a "proper" grip.

This, by the way, is critical in pistol and rifle shooting. In fact, there are certain types of shooting where there is a direct parallel: slow-aimed-fire. Anything from match pistol, match rifle, Olympic-style bialthon (which uses a .22 cal weapon), benchrest and the new "lightgun" style used for the (ridiculously dumbed down modern rules of) pentathlon.

In all of these cases either a *single* shot is going out and it counts for everything, or the shooter is given a relatively huge amount of time to line up follow-on shots (so recoil isn't a factor aside from not hurting the shooter, as in the extreme range competitions where the guns kick a little harder than normal). The triggers on these weapons are as light as mechanics (or rules) permit, the grips are highly specialized to assist a shooter in locking the weapon to the body but with as little linear contact as possible, and the *shooter assumes as stable a position as possible*.

OTOH, close-range tactical shooting is *rarely* slow-aimed-fire. (Which is why the standard U.S. Army pistol test is not at all a reflection of combat competency but our old SFARTAETC "stress test", while still flawed, is *much* better -- and neither hold a candle to Bill Rogers' "reactive range" tests.)

**Its all about body position**

The importance of the stability of the firing position *and grip* cannot be understated because the trigger-pull itself is what will throw your shot. If you happen to have a laser pointer handy, turn it on, point it at a wall at least 10 feet away, and just see how steadily you can hold it on a 1-inch circle without doing anything else. Then try it sitting down. Then raise a knee sitting down and rest your hand on that. Then do it while breathing deeply. Then lay down and try it.

The magical answer to your question comes when you try the same exercise as above, but this time apply some stiff pressure from a finger into your grip. Try different fingers. Try pushing, sliding, pressing, yanking in different directions with different fingers, and watch what happens to your laser point (protip: it'll go totally wild most of the time).

To be even more accurate, put something similar to a Star Trek phaser -- like a TV remote -- in your hand and tape the laser pointer to it. See how steadily you can maintain your point of aim *as you press buttons on it*. This will tell you a lot about how practical the grip in the shows is.

**My two cents**

My suspicion is that its not a a good grip for an energy weapon unless they *always* lock the wrist bones down at the same angle and fully stress the ligaments on top, which sucks to do for more than a few seconds. I can't imagine that this would work out well in practice. Oh, did I mention, shoulder joints are inherently unstable...

Also, two hands always beats one; you can limit fundamental instability to just one dimension instead of three, and use opposing tension within a two-handed, cupped grip to stabilize the weapon as the trigger is pulled/button pressed/whatever. This is why gangsta-grip tends to result in a lot of sky-high fliers or ankle-level shots, even at very close range (for a right-hander they tend to be very high to the right or very low to the left -- but we're all quirky little snowflakes, which is why it is impossible to design "the perfect trigger/grip" pair).

...*Unless they actually use a mental or voice activation we're not aware of*. Or a button in the other hand. Or computer activation. Or... you get the idea. This would be totally badass and is *the* way to do high precision shots properly. But even then, its hard to hold a laser pointer at something very long with the confidence that you will destroy it (and *only* it) when the thing goes off when doing so with just one hand.

...*Unless the energy weapon is itself somehow auto-aimed within a certain degree of accuracy*. Considering we are trending toward modern weapons of this form today, I think its somewhat safe to retcon this aspect of mechanical assistance in accuracy into the Trek world.

EDIT: Something I failed to notice or mention initially, but grew curious about checking out a few Star Trek clips is that they appear to often be pointing the weapon with one hand and activating the trigger with the thumb. This is a *terrible* idea. The only reason we have triumphed over the other apes is our brains, but our further success over dolphins is due exclusively to our thumbs. There is only one on each hand. Without a very specialized grip that permits pressure from the metacarpal of the thumb to be the *exclusive* opposing retainer to all four gripping fingers (which is actually possible, but very tiring/cramp prone in practice -- srsly, try it), using a *thumb* to activate the trigger is almost a *guarantee* that you will throw your shot.

**...and we'll just forget about those pesky aiming devices...**

Something I did not address at all, but is absolutely critical, is the concept of "sight picture". There appear to be no sights on these things at all. Something the size of a TV remote can unhinge a bank vault door, but it apparently lacks a reliable aiming mechanism for all that power. Man, I sure hope these guys practice a *lot*, because they are *always shooting from the hip*. Shooting from the hip can be rather accurate though, out to about 25 yards. But beyond that the law of squares just eats you for lunch... (an inch off-target at 10m is how many inches off-target at 500m? *You need sights on your scary-powerful energy weapon*)

Comment: Marking this as the accepted answer as I find it more detailed and extremely insightful.

Comment: The [phaser rifles](http://i.imgur.com/NqEf1ny.jpg) do have an aiming thing.

Comment: @Sklivvz Indeed. I wrote this mostly with the banana-lasers in mind (which seems to be the explicit intent of the OP), but figured a bit more background in marksmanship would give the OP a better picture of what is involved in judging a firing posture. A *lot* more goes into shooting than "point and click", and much of the detail is not usually obvious to a non-shooter (and even most shooters).

Comment: Dolphins are definitely very smart as these things go, and there is certainly an absolutely massive amount we don’t know about them, but to say that only our thumbs (and not our brains) give us an advantage over them is a massive overstatement. If nothing else, that’s certainly not something that humanity has managed to determine with any certainty, and in fact, available data (incomplete though it is) suggests quite the opposite. Beware popular science reporting on the subject of animal intelligence; it is almost-always overstating both our certainty and our results.

Comment: `Unless the energy weapon is itself somehow auto-aimed within a certain degree of accuracy` - I have a very vague recollection of this being mentioned somewhere

Comment: @Izkata In this case I think it is a horrible mistake to even have them be hand operated. A much more practical arrangement is integration with a collar or headgear for carriage (leaving the operator hands-free whether engaged or not), auto-aim based on tracking eye movement, and fire triggered by either a muscle trigger or neuro-trigger. We're working on such things today, so I would assume they are pretty ordinary in the far future, especially with recoilless directed energy weapons.

Comment: Well, we know they have [detached sights](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/3/33/Ezri_dax_tr116.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20090126063047&path-prefix=en) for other weapons

Comment: I do agree about the trigger pull problem--I have the same problem with a little pocket camera--holding it stable while pushing the button doesn't happen.  That being said, I don't think it really matters--phasers only need to hit their target, they don't need to hit it accurately and at the range the ones with bad triggers are used it's not going to matter if they're shooting from the hip if they're reasonably competent.  For longer ranges they use weapons that can be aimed properly.  (Admittedly, I haven't seen all the newer stuff, maybe they don't follow this later on.)

Comment: @LorenPechtel Considering that they don't have to hit the target accurately, the hazard inherent in hitting the *wrong* target drastically increases. On the range we tend to face rather sterile firing environments (outside of advanced training), but in the real world I've *rarely* been presented with a totally clean, completely unambiguous environment downrange of my weapon. Confusion reigns: your buddy just fell in front of you and *might not know to stay down until someone behind him picks him up* and so is rising into your shot, kids run out of doorways suddenly, you trip on stuff, etc.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Please not I'm not at all disagreeing with you at all -- my point is that absolute destruction is a double-edged sword, and the backswing of that particular issue will have to be taken into account by the procurement, design, evaluation and training sections of an organization employing this weapon.

Comment: @zxq9 When do they ever fight with non-combatants in the field of fire??

Comment: @LorenPechtel This point is, perhaps, the most utterly unrealistic element of the whole situation. :-) ...though I do seem to recall there being phasers fired onboard Federation ships from time to time -- this is probably the most complex situation possible where there really is no clean field of fire (doors and hallways everywhere, sensitive equipment, people rushing about, etc.).

Comment: an inch off target at 10 means 50 inches off target at 500 (it's linear)

Comment: @lzkata, yes, maybe in Star Trek Enterprise, I recall some training session where some officer or other complains about how the old "manual" sights were better but the instructor reassures that the new ones are better and just takes some time getting used to.

Comment: The one thing I miss in this answer is one *huge* difference compared to projectile weapons - the phaser "shot" lasts for a really long time. From a fraction of a second to upwards of several seconds. There seems to be a really long time for the person firing to readjust their aim dynamically. Like "painting" the target with light. It's also not like tracer bullets, which are relatively slow to travel. The feedback looks instant - shooting from the hip must be much easier to develope a technique for when you see your "shot" at all times and can subconsciously adjust your aim.

Comment: @Prof.Falken Indeed, phaser shots do last a long time. I can't recall an instance where a phaser was fired and then moved on target, though there are plenty of cases where a phaser, once striking a target, tracks it as it moves (at least the ship-borne ones). I suppose this raises the question of how the targetting mechanism (which clearly must exist) identifies its target, or is it "manual" in the sense of constantly tracking eye movement (hrm, scary -- "*don't* glance at the tits!"). (Tracers are the same speed as the rest of the rounds they are loaded to match, btw.)

Comment: @Prof.Falken I forget to mention... tracers are also not very useful in practice. They are mostly a good way for a squad weapon or a squad leader to mark a target by shooting at it a few times -- but other than this niche case, just don't really do much for us in practice. (Well, they start fires a lot, which is usually not what we want -- but everything seems to catch fire in a fight eventually anyway.)

Comment: @zxq9, I share this recollection - the phasers mostly hit and then track, never miss and then "pick up" the right target. Some things maybe are hard to retcon and must be chalked up to production/film making. Yes, I imagine tracers are the same speed as bullets, but my point is that phaser fire seems incredibly fast - phaser sweeps never look like "bent", like water, it always looks like a straight line.

Comment: @zxq9, a bit OT, but interesting tidbit about how tracer fire is not that useful in practice, thx.

Comment: @Prof.Falken More like shining a laser than shooting a stream of bullets. With that in mind, to satisfy the laws of retcon I think we must conclude/retcon that they are aimed by an internal mechanism that receives input it can perceive from the user (eye tracking seems the best option), and perhaps shape/motion/distance identification with lasers & optics once engaged. In this case any grip will suffice, and actually gripping them at all is a mistake. (Re. tracers: One big problem is that they point both ways, especially at night; I never *once* used them when I was in special units.)

Comment: @zxq9 good viewpoints. One path I think is seriously underexplored in retconning, is the tendency of humans to be conservative. Look at military equipment, how cumbersome, heavy and conservative much of it is, (but not everything, of course). I think the same can be applied to Star Trek in many instances. Why not more neuro interfaces for instance? Or fancy shoulder mounted phaser pistols etc? Why, because of conservative generals and inertia and weapons testing etc and conventions.

Comment: @Prof.Falken - You may have a (very) small point, but you've clearly little experience. Military stuff is heavy and conservative for a reason - it _has_ to work under conditions of mud, snow, abuse and dog-tired users. Example - I was a door gunner in Vietnam. A platoon was not responding to radio calls, so we went to find them. The RTO was taking a break in a rice paddy by sitting on his radio, which was mostly submerged. The ubiquitous AK47 is not a great rifle - poor accuracy and a not-great cartridge. What is shines at is astounding reliability. Compare to early M16s.

Comment: @whatroughbeast, so add ruggedness to the list... :-) Yes I have very little experience

Comment: I'm asking my self what gives with one hand 3 dimensions where a second hand limits the inaccuracy to 1 dimension. All I could think of is if you are counting the distance so a recoil backwardpushing recoil would be the 3 dimension. but then I can't see how a second hand would cross that effect out. So I can jsut see 3 dimensions where a second hand would reduce the error to still 2 dimensions. Or in the case thats not considered, I aggree a 2nd hand limits the error to 1 dimension but I can't see where there even are 3 possible dimensions for 1 handed use.

Comment: @Zaibis As a firing platform your hand is very complex. By using two hands you limit the fingers and wrist in a proper grip by locking the fingers, skin and wrist bones (laterally) with opposing tension. By extending the arms to form a triangle (as in, *not Jack Bauer's Weaver stance* wtf) you limit play from the elbows and shoulders. The *platform* (hands) can now move just up and down (turn with your feet or twist at the waist, eyes aligned, to traverse). Alignment with the eye and *watching the action during recoil* while you *focus on the front sight post* takes care of the rest.

Comment: @zxq9: But wouldn't my shoulder be a limit for one hand aswell so just having the options of moving right/left + up/down? since my extended arm would be stabilized by my shoulder?

Comment: @Zaibis Your shoulder is a free-floating mass of muscle and ligaments, not a joint in the same sense a hip is. When you straighten both arms together you roll your shoulder forward, locking it together with tension through the tissue (similar to the way twisting a bundle of rope makes it hard, and untwisting it leaves it a blob of soft, loose fiber). You can lock one elbow, but recoil will unlock it and pull your hand out of alignment in a 3D spiral (unless you are using a *very* small caliber). This fundamental instability makes moving while shooting like this is *very* difficult.

Comment: @Zaibis To *really* understand you need to go to the range. There are a thousand minute revelations one must experience before really getting it. It is very similar to jiu-jutsu in the sense that you can spend a lot of time trying things and practicing and still have a bunch of "ah ha!" moments. The body in motion is complex.

Comment: @zxq9: Ok, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: It is a little-known fact that the silly little phasers in the original Star Trek series actually did have an aimsight. It was a reflex type site where one was actually looking through the weapon's optics. You can see it here: http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/sidearmenergy.php#phaserreflex

Answer (score 43):

Having fired a weapon is not a prerequisite to answer this question.  Shooting stance (with real firearms) aids in aiming and compensating for recoil.  [Phasers](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Type_2_phaser#24th_century_and_beyond), on the other hand, have no recoil, and in some incarnations of the show, have targeting computers.  But this is easy to test yourself, with a laser pointer.

[image]

If you hold a laser pointer in the same way that O'Brien is holding his in this picture, you get a clear view down the body of the weapon.  If you press the laser pointer, you should (and I do, but I cannot create a video of myself to show this) hit whatever it is you are aiming at.  It is relatively easy to aim such a weapon at close range.

This experiment does fail on one point, however.  My laser pointer is a straight cylinder, not a banana shape.  The banana shape of TNG and later era phasers make them MUCH more comfortable to hold and aim.  Just hold our your arm in line with your eye, and your hand will naturally fall into a position to hold the weapon.

This is not to mention the various times in the run of the series when hand phasers have or have not had targeting aids.  This would be a very comfortable, and possibly very accurate weapon.

Comparing to a modern handgun is a little tricky though.  The only handgun I have fired is a [Colt M1911](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M1911_pistol) which, in my hands, has a little bit of a kick.  The handhold is a little uncomfortable to me, but if the grip were in the position a TNG era phaser used, I am sure I would have broken my wrist.

Comment: Very interested, had never ocurred to me to try with a laser pointer!

Comment: For a more accurate experiment, stick the laser pointer into a banana.

Comment: @coredump god damn beat me to it

Comment: @coredump "Into" not "onto"? That's a nasty image... thanks... thanks a lot.

Comment: It's a good question about targetting aids. But there's a big difference between a phaser and a rifle or other sighted weapon: with the phaser you can correct while the beam is still on, so you don't need sights. It might even be tactically advantagous to cut the beam across a target rather than try to hit dead on with the first shot. +1

Comment: Ohh, hold a straight edge up to that picture. The phaser beam continues the line drawn between the phaser tip (barrel? focus?) and O'Brien's eyes! (I get somewhere directly between them on his nasal bridge, but the perspective widening of the beam leaves it a bit open to interpretation.) I wonder if they [designed it that way...](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/101969)

Comment: @coredump You finally found something better than sharks with lasers strapped to their heads

Comment: @ToddWilcox Yet oddly everyone seems to be such as good shot that there are very few occasions where we actually see the beam moving at all during fire.  The one episode I recall this happening was, I believe, TNG:Legacy, and this was only because the person firing the beam weapon was hit and fell backwards while still discharging their firearm. Even in target practice the beam doesn't move: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tR97q35_3nw

Comment: I feel like this picture was cherry-picked a bit to show a more "aimed" firing stance than the TNG-era characters usually display.  I don't have time to track down other references right now, but O'Brien appears not only to be holding the phaser higher than usual, but also snugging his chin down into his shoulder a bit to get closer to a direct line of sight parallel to the beam (although that may just be the low angle of the photo).  I think the majority of hand-phaser action stills from TNG, DS9, and VOY would probably show that the characters do _not_ usually sight in line with the beam.

Comment: @Tritium21 I'm not clear what makes you think the 1911 pistol you fired would have broken your wrist if you held it with the barrel more in line with your arm.  If anything perceived "kick" is _less_ the higher your grip on a pistol (because more of the energy of the recoil is transferred directly through the bones and joints of your arm into your body).  Also, a standard steel-framed WWII issue .45 is actually considered _soft_-recoiling as pistols go by gun enthusiasts, thanks to its weight and the relatively low speed of the projectile (vs., e.g., a titanium-frame revolver in .357 magnum).

Comment: @dodgethesteamroller This is the first picture that came up on google image search with a type 2 phaser.  And holding a 1911 the way you would hold a phaser (comfortably tilted forward) would apply vertical pressure to the wrist (as opposed to horizontally back against the wrist).

Comment: The 1911 wouldn't have broken your wrist unless your wrists are built really cheap -- those are pretty light-recoil pistols (with nothing to compare it to, though, I imagine the violence of your first shots would have left an impression). Holding it like O'Brien does in the picture would, however, have cut the crap out of your hands because of the way the slide and hammer operate. Gripping high is good for stability, but there is a problem with cutting the webbing of your hand or knuckles on the bottom edge of the slide (common enough its got a nickname: "slide bite").

Comment: @dodgethesteamroller: Using Google Images for "tng phaser firing" brings up various stills of 24th century Starfleet handheld phasers being fired. While a few of them are quirky, it is indeed noticeable how in most of the stills, the firing person holds the phaser very high, almost in front of their eyes.

Comment: There are very phaser like presentation aids with laser pointers activated by a thumb button. I have one, and I gotta say, I don't think your conclusion is correct. Hitting a target on the first try is all but impossible. I mean, sure, I can hit my fridge at 20ft, but a picture on the fridge? Not even close.

Answer (score 7):

There are no sights on phasers, but everyone assumes they are manually aimed.  I don't see any reason why that's true.

Here's how it works, I think: you point it in the general direction you want to shoot, you *look* at the thing you want to shoot at, and a camera on the top of the phaser using sophisticated eye tracking technology determines what you're looking at.  Another camera on the front of the phaser (dangerous end) takes a picture of the target area and using advanced image recognition, programmed rules, and what your eyes are looking at, it determines what you want to shoot at.  It then projects a targeting beam at the spot that it's selected, which the shooter can see.  If the spot's on the right target, the shooter presses the button.  The phaser doesn't have to be pointed exactly right, because the emitter uses [phased array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phased_array) technology to steer the beam towards the target.

At least that's how I always envisioned it working.

**Edited to Add**

From DS9: [Return to Grace](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Return_to_Grace_%28episode%29):

> KIRA: This is a standard issue, Cardassian phase-disruptor rifle. It has a four point seven megajoule power capacity, three millisecond recharge two beam settings.
>
> ZIYAL: How do you know so much about Cardassian weapons?
>
> KIRA: We captured a lot of them during the occupation. It's a good weapon, solid, simple. You can drag it through the mud and it'll still fire. Now this. (Federation phaser rifle.) This is an entirely different animal. Federation standard issue. It's a little less powerful, but it's got a more options. Sixteen beam settings. Fully autonomous recharge, **multiple target acquisition, gyro stabilised**, the works. It's a little more complicated, so it's not as good a field weapon. Too many things can go wrong with it.

I think that indicates there's more to a phaser than simply shooting a beam where you point it.

Comment: I really liked the phased array idea.

Comment: Even if physically the phaser doesn't need to be pointed exactly, the beam needs to be pointed, in the case of phased arrays such pointing happens by moving something internally to the phaser or by computing phases for different waves wich results in the need of auotmatic aiming

Comment: Sorry but you're giving no Canon source for this answer and if I remember correctly there's evidence in canon this is NOT the way it actually works. Training in the holodeck (as we see multiple times) wouldn't make a lot of sense plus your system does not work as good as you think it would. What happens if there're two potential targets in close proximity? How does the phaser know which one to target... there's a lot of technology in ST but mind reading is not one of them

Comment: @JorgeCórdoba - I have seen at least one episode where they were training in the holodeck, and it still seemed like this is the way it must work. Clearly they weren't pointing them exactly at the target. It seemed to me that the training was all about proper focus on the target, and perhaps using consistent gestures, etc., to make sure the targeting system on the phaser was able to correctly interpret what you were looking it. You still have to physically point it in the general direction quickly, and focus your gaze on the target, see the target beam and press a button. It all needs practice.

Comment: Which begs the question, despite a phaser's general level of sophistication and the potential of 24th century technology, how come so many miss using a phaser when aiming. Moreover, if very large phasers are installed on a ship with a super-sophisticated shipcomputer capable of near AI, how come ships firing at each other miss each other, often at close range?

Comment: Another super sophisticated near AI computer trying to escape the shot. As far as eye track is concerned a proof of concept of that can be made today (afaik Attack helicopters do it today), so 300 years in future....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming energy weapons in the future have no recoil, holding them loosely is of no importance. Then again the actors were never trained in weapons utilization. Phasers were as much tools as they were weapons in the Star Trek series. 
Also various episodes show that phasers had "auto targeting" though they still missed.
[image]

The phasers evolved over the progress of the series, resembling guns, then resembling wands tools. As the series progressed past TNG, proper hand holding of phasers and other weapons became more ergonomic for hands. Alien weapons on the other hand continued to resemble guns. There's no realistic way of holding a phaser, such technology doesn't exist but later models clearly showcase the weapon having black molded grips and continuing to curve to comfortably be held in the hand. 
Truthfully if I was designing a phaser I would study the ergonomics of prior firearms, where the defense industry spent years crafting firearms for adequate ergonomics. However NOT everyone in starfleet is Human so ergonomics must have given wave to practicality, a weapon that Any species in the Federation can hold adequately.